# How can I get the list of available arguments for a PHP function?

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the available arguments for a PHP function?

Example: I want to call `function1($arg1, $arg2=null)`. How can I find out, before calling the function, the number of arguments this function takes, and, if it's possible, what arguments?

As you can see, I am dynamically calling functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ReflectionFunction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php#language.oop5.reflection.reflectionfunction)

Comment: Thank you. I had to juggle a bit more to get where i want but that's what i was looking for

Comment: You're welcome. If, for some reason, you can't load the code into the runtime, you could also use `token_get_all` to parse the source code. It's probably not applicable to your situation, but just wanted to mention the option, in case some one else reads this and have that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following functions from inside the function that is being called to determine how many arguments were passed and to get their values.  I'm not sure how you would check what arguments a function expects.

[func_num_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

[func_get_arg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php)

[func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, via `ReflectionFunction`. However, PHP functions can use [variable arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) and in that case it's impossible to tell.

Comment: func_get_args() gives you the arguments passed to a function. I think the question is how to find out the argument list for a given function